# MethodError points to a constant

Tags: julia

I made a function that finds the jacobian of a set of differential equations.

```
global alpha = 1
global gamma = 0.001
global s = -0.5
global delta = 0.1
global k_1 = 0.01
global k_2 = 0.02
global k_3 = 0.008 # medium secretion
global k_4 = 10^-2
global N_0 = 10^6
global m = k_4 * N_0


function calc_jacobian(a,b,c,g)

    jac = [[-k_1 - gamma + alpha*(1 + s)*(1 - ((1/N_0)*(2*a + b + c))), k_2 + alpha*(1 + s)*a*(-1/N_0), alpha*(1 + s)*a*(-1/N_0), 0],[k_1, -k_2 - k_3 - gamma, k_4*g, k_4*c],[alpha*(1 + s)*b*(-1/N_0) + alpha*c*(-1/N_0), alpha*(1 + s)*(1 - ((1/N_0)*(a + 2*b + c))) + alpha*c*(-1/N_0) + k_4, alpha*(1 + s)*b*(-1/N_0) + alpha*(1-((1/N_0)*(a + b + 2*c))) + k_4*g - gamma, -k_4*c],[gamma*delta, gamma, -k_4*g, -k_4*c - gamma]]

    return jac
end

calc_jacobian(1.0,1.0,0.0,1.0)
```

When I call the function I get a MethodError:

```
MethodError: objects of type Float64 are not callable
in top-level scope at steady_state.jl:20
in calc_jacobian at steady_state.jl:4
```

steady_state.jl is the name of the file.

Why is the MethodError coming up and why does it mention the line `global delta = 0.1` in the error message?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The code works fine to run for me. Perhaps restart Julia and make sure you evaluate everything from the beginning?

Comment: Thank you for your help. Restarting did help. I am still curious why did this error come up. I had run a few codes with the same delta as a constant and those codes worked.

Answer (score 0):

Welcome Sanji! I usually get that error when I do something like:

```
a = .3
b = 10
c = b + a(5 + b)
```

and for get the asterisk multiplying the `a` and the `(...)`.

I'm guessing that line came up because you may have defined the functioned without the `delta*...` at some point.

Comment: Thanks a ton for the explaination, but it appears that I have no function without delta*... and this is my first time actually using it in this ay. However, I rewrote the matrix in the form of  `[a b c; d e ...]` instead of `[[a,b,c],[d,e,..]]` without changing anything anywhere, the same code ran without throwing any error. I can't seem to understand this behaviour.

Comment: Understandable - because Julia let's you define functions as you go, sometimes you get stuck where you keep calling a wrong function you defined some time ago. I guess this is why sometimes restarting and running the code again will work - you will no longer be calling those incorrect methods.